# VirtualBox: USB hub not detected on Linux Guest - MacOS Host

Tags: linux, macos, usb, virtualbox

I am trying to connect multiple USB devices to my Linux guest through the use of a USB hub, however, it seems that the hub is not detected on the guest. In my tests I have noted the following:

- The USB hub works fine if connected directly to the Mac OS.
- The USB hub works fine if connected to a Linux guest with a Windows host.
- The USB hub + connected devices are not registered when connected to the Linux guest (Mac host). There is no change to the output of #lsusb or #dmesg

Which indicates that it is a problem with VirtualBox on Mac hosts. Is there anyway I can overcome this and detect my USB hub + devices on my Linux guest?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will it pass all USB devices currently plugged into the hub, if plugged into the host directly, one at a time (without the hub)?

Comment: Yes. I have tried three different USB devices and connected them directly to the linux guest and they were detected. I have also tried connecting them directly to the MacOS host and again they were detected.

Comment: Have you installed the guest addon pack for VirtualBox?

Comment: Is this hub USB3 or USB2? Ditto for the connected devices. Is the VB extension pack installed?

Comment: This is a USB2 Hub. All connected devices are USB2. I have installed the VB extension pack. As I said, I have two identical Linux guests, one on Mac and one on Windows, and the problem only occurs on Mac. Thanks.

Comment: Can you comment in your post where you get stuck in [this procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20066190/165358) and in [this one](http://egostino.wordpress.com/2012/10/27/virtualbox-mac-osx-ubuntu-usb-disk-problem/). Try also to disconnect/reconnect the usb devices several times.

Comment: @harrymc In the first link, in step 7, I don't want to add the devices individually, I want to create a USB filter to let all devices go through to the VM guest. This is necessary in my case as the devices are continuously changed. A USB filter works on a VM with Windows host. In the second link, I get stuck in the second step as no devices appear on neither the guest not the host, I'm guessing because I have a USB filter enabled. Thanks for your input though as now I can add the devices individually to the guest as an intermediate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For automatically connecting specific devices [create a USB filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20066190/165358) :

1. Close virtualbox
2. Execute in bash: `sudo adduser YOURUSERNAME vboxusers` (if required)
3. Attach the USB devices you want to be automatically mounted in the VM (virtual machine).
4. Open Virtualbox
5. From menu, go to "File" -> "Preferences" -> "General".
6. Select your VM and go to "Machine" -> "Settings" -> "USB".
7. Check "Enable USB Controller"; click on the icon with the USB plug and the plus, and 
   click on the devices you want to be automatically mounted in the VM. Click "Ok".
8. Click on "Start" toolbar button, and ensure your USB devices are recognized and 
   mounted by the VM. Remember that you have to unmount them in the host OS too if you have 
   to disconnect them after you exit the VM.

[image]

Comment: This will work with USB devices but not with USB hubs.